# Error causing Forced Closure in Questionnaire Android App

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on an app written three years ago in Eclipse for Android Devices. After downloading Android Studio, I decided to test the app using the default testing device Nexus_5_API_22_x86 [emulator-5554].

As I test the app, I get to the last step where the final question in the questionnaire is answered, the button label is replaced with the text "Finish". However, I get the below error from Android Studio when the application crashes.

I'm not an android developer (I'm actually a Web Application Developer using PHP, MySQL, JS / jQuery so on...) but I do have some experience with Java (Albeit not a lot, but I'll get there) My understanding of the error has lead me to three functions which I have followed and they seem to be ok.

*FYI: I was not the developer who wrote this app.*

Can anyone suggest what I should be looking for ?

```
07-04 14:48:28.331  15408-15408/au.com.psychic.psychictest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: au.com.psychic.psychictest, PID: 15408
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
        at au.com.psychic.psychictest.Questions.GetResult(Questions.java:110)
        at au.com.psychic.psychictest.MainActivity.setQuestion(MainActivity.java:68)
        at au.com.psychic.psychictest.MainActivity.nextQuestion(MainActivity.java:90)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly states ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Your program is trying to access some array's 4th element when the size of array is 3. You should have a look at the line numbers specified in the error, in the respective files.

>

```
at au.com.psychic.psychictest.Questions.GetResult(Questions.java:110)
        at au.com.psychic.psychictest.MainActivity.setQuestion(MainActivity.java:68)
        at au.com.psychic.psychictest.MainActivity.nextQuestion(MainActivity.java:90)
```

Also, you can try debugging your code, that can help.

Comment: What debuggers would you recommend? When I tried the debugger in Android Studio, it gave me less debugging information than the standard Run option :/

Comment: You can either use log messages in your code using the Log class, or you can use breakpoints. Clicking on the side-bar to the left should add a breakpoint. Then you can run your app in the debug mode.
The following link might help
https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html